# Nodemon installation errorproblem

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm-QXjMEw5N
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm-QXjMEw5N'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm-QXjMEw5N'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.npm-QXjMEw5N'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-01T20_20_59_514Z-debug.log
```

i run `npm install -g nodemon`

but it gives the error above

Answer (score 2):

You can understand what is happening by reading the error log

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm-QXjMEw5N'
```

EPERM is the code for the permission issue. Here, you cannot create (mkdir) a new directory called .npm-QXjMEw5N inside `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\` because you don't have the permission to do that.

> Macro: int EPERM “Operation not permitted.”
>
> Only the owner of the file
> (or other resource) or processes with special privileges can perform
> the operation.

You can try running the command line as administrator to have the appropriate privilege, then rerun `npm install -g nodemon`

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your cache then install again? Something like npm cache clear --force then npm i